# What is the status of HTML/CSS layout questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope, doctype

What is the current status of HTML/CSS layout, and/or web design questions? Are they fully allowed on SO, or are they *still* expected to go to Doctype?

Yes, I *know* this is the same as the [CSS on Doctype?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/do-css-questions-belong-on-so-or-doctype) question. The difference is, that's a year old question, and I can't find the FAQ reference it mentions, so things might have changed.

I'm trying to decide if I should commit to [**Web Design** (now deleted)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22803/web-design). If HTML/CSS is fine on SO, then I don't see any reason to. However, if HTML/CSS is supposed to go to Doctype, then I *would* support the proposal - whatever its value, Doctype *isn't* part of the SE supergroup, and I'm not interested in creating yet another account on it. :)

Account-creation actually isn't the *only* reason I don't want to go to Doctype, there's also losing all the cool SO 2.0 features. I'm really liking the envelop/triangle replacement. Every time I go to UnityAnswers (1.0), I miss all the new stuff :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The status *quo* is that HTML and CSS questions [are being merrily asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html?sort=newest&pagesize=30) on SO proper, and get a lot of feedback there so I don't see a need to create a new site for this.

I think that Doctype cooperation phased out somehow. There's never been any official campaign or guideline to send askers of HTML questions there, at least not since I've been on board.

Questions that totally focus on Design and have no real connection to the markup would be better suited on the new [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) Stack exchange site.

Comment: As questions are merrily being asked, users are merrily [answering their way to gold badges](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/topusers). Namely, myself and thirtydot :P

Comment: Works for me. And it's one less proposal I need to follow. :)