# Is there a place for questions about HTML semantics or accessibility?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, scope

I'm wondering where (if anywhere) to ask questions about HTML semantics and/or accessibility.

Examples:

- What is the correct way to semantically mark up a form?
- When should definition lists be used?
- What is the difference between `<em>` and `<i>` in HTML5?
- When is a `<div>` more appropriate than a `<p>` tag?
- How do I write proper alt text for icons?

Stack Overflow doesn't seem like the place, and neither does [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) or [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). Nothing on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) seemed to be appropriate either.

Some of these examples are somewhat subjective, but not completely. I have seen similar questions on Stack Overflow, they seemed technically off topic or were borderline.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the right place for all those questions.

See e.g. these questions: (They're not always 100% dupes of yours but they come close)

- [Why use definition lists (DL,DD,DT) tags for HTML forms instead of tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519234/why-use-definition-lists-dl-dd-dt-tags-for-html-forms-instead-of-tables)
- [When is the best time to use <b> and <i> in lieu of <strong> and <em>, if ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752/when-is-the-best-time-to-use-b-and-i-in-lieu-of-strong-and-em-if-ever)
- [What is the difference between <p> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226562/what-is-the-difference-between-p-and-div)
- [Is alt="" appropriate in some situations for html img tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806326/is-alt-appropriate-in-some-situations-for-html-img-tag)

Comment: @Wesley HTML questions are historically accepted, partly probably because they're the tool of so many programmers, partly probably because of the traffic they bring - it would be stupid to turn that away. See e.g. [What is the status of HTML/CSS layout questions on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85675)