# Why was this question about schema.org closed by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889199/how-to-use-schema-org-to-markup-a-forum) was closed by a moderator 3 months after the last activity occurred.

Furthermore, the reason was specified as "off topic". I don't see how that applies to this question, since it's relevant to programmers writing web forum software.

Why was this question closed?

Comment: That's not a programming question.  It might belong on Web Masters, but it's definitely not programming.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I was under the impression that [asking about html semantics was OK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91379/is-there-a-place-for-questions-about-html-semantics-or-accessibility), is this not completely true? We allow HTML and CSS questions but technically neither of those are programming languages... If anything, the post may have crossed the line of subjective/not-constructive, but it's not clear to me how it's off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary reason for me closing the question as "off topic" was this statement:

> Obviously schema.org will never be a complete ontology. So what is the process for dealing with things that aren't in the spec? I see schema.org discusses extending the spec, but will search engines actually understand this and be able to turn it into something useful?

This deals with two things that are not on topic for Stack Overflow:

- Dealing with things not defined in the spec, that's an issue to take up with the people who are writing the spec (unless it's specified otherwise)
- How will search engines understand the application of a non-complete ontology (very much off topic for Stack Overflow).

This doesn't count the other issues that the post has:

- There was no example HTML given that the code should have been applied to, or even better, HTML with the markup applied.  This begs the question "what did you do", which qualifies it as NARQ.
- The following excerpt:

  > It doesn't seem right to markup the original post as an article, and every post after that a comment.

  This begs the question "what is right" which classifies it as "not constructive".

"Off topic" might not sit well with everyone, and we could open and re-close it to something more appropriate that the community agrees upon, but I think the important thing was accomplished; the question was closed as it was simply not appropriate for the site.

At this point, the only reason to change the close reason would be to indicate what the most glaring issues are with the question, but given that it's not just *one* glaring issue, *any* close reason given might not be enough to indicate to the poster what can be done to resurrect the question.

Also, in regards to [Madmartigan's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122964/why-was-this-question-about-schema-org-closed-by-a-moderator/122974#comment327321_122964), asking about HTML semantics is OK for Stack Overflow, but asking about semantics without providing examples of the HTML to apply the semantics too, or showing how you've *already* applied the semantics ("what did you do") isn't going to get much (if any) love at all.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my comment, but I admit I merely scanned the post at first. Nothing was lost deleting the post, and the only answer is a wild guess with a request for examples.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an extensive reply.

Comment: @CyberShadow NP